# How to generate a map out of all translator "string".tr string in my app using Flutter Getx localization

Tags: flutter, flutter-getx

As mentioned in [GetX Documations](https://pub.dev/packages/get#utils) to use GetX Localization I should create a `messages.dart` file that contains a map for every language as this one :

```dart
import 'package:get/get.dart';

class Messages extends Translations {
  @override
  Map<String, Map<String, String>> get keys => {
        'en_US': {
          'hello': 'Hello World',
        },
        'de_DE': {
          'hello': 'Hallo Welt',
        }
      };
}
```

Then call the value of every string using the .tr method like `"hello".tr` and it will show the value based on the current locale.

Now in my case the process is reversed as I have a complete flutter application that has all strings written as `"String".tr` and I need a way to list all strings and generate a JSON map out of it .. or even list all strings then I will manually create the `messages.dart` file.